# How to block write in combo box?

Tags: autoit

How to deny a text with AutoIt in input (combo, edit.. etc.), or deny to write in other input?

```
Func GUIListeConfigs()
Global $GUIListeConfigs = GUICreate("Configs", 319, 156, 684, 408, -1, BitOR(0x00000080,0x00000008,0x08000000, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST))
    $GroupBox1 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("", 8, 1, 305, 97)
    Global $Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("", 72, 56, 169, 25)
    $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Selectionnez une Configuration", 48, 16, 226, 24)
    GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 12, 400, 0, "MS Sans Serif")
    GUICtrlCreateGroup("", -99, -99, 1, 1)
    Global $ButtonChargerConfig = GUICtrlCreateButton("&OK", 73, 107, 75, 25)
    $cEnterDummy = GUICtrlCreateDummy()
    Local $aAccelKeys[1][2] = [["{ENTER}", $cEnterDummy]]
    GUISetAccelerators($aAccelKeys)
    Global $ButtonAnnulerChargerConfig = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 170, 107, 75, 25)
    GUISetState(@SW_HIDE, $GUIListeConfigs)
    #EndRegion ### END Koda GUI secw²tion ###
EndFunc
```

Comment: [`GUICtrlSetState($Combo1, $GUI_DISABLE)`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetState.htm) possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your are looking for?

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include<ComboConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    ; Create a GUI with various controls.
    Local $hGUI = GUICreate("Example", 300, 200)

    ; Create a combobox control.
    Local $idComboBox = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Item 1", 10, 10, 185, 20, bitOR($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_COMBO, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST))
    Local $idButton_Close = GUICtrlCreateButton("Close", 210, 170, 85, 25)

    ; Add additional items to the combobox.
    GUICtrlSetData($idComboBox, "Item 2|Item 3", "Item 2")

    ; Display the GUI.
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)

    Local $sComboRead = ""

    ; Loop until the user exits.
    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE, $idButton_Close
                ExitLoop
            Case $idComboBox
                $sComboRead = GUICtrlRead($idComboBox)
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The combobox is currently displaying: " & $sComboRead, 0, $hGUI)
        EndSwitch
    WEnd

    ; Delete the previous GUI and all controls.
    GUIDelete($hGUI)
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```